# Python: How do I extract lines in a log file from an hour ago until now

Tags: python, logging, extract

I'm not even sure on where to start.. All I've read up on is how to do in bash but looking to write it in python

Example log lines:

```
Sep 8 13:25:02 blah
Sep 8 13:25:02 blahblah
Sep 8 13:25:02 blahblahblah
```

Comment: You should at least make an attempt. I can bet the solution to this exact task is on the internet at least 100 times over

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Hint. You need to turn a string like "Sep 8 13:25:02" into something you can do arithmetic with. Look at the `datetime` module and the method `datetime.datetime.strptime()`.

Comment: @BoarGules Thanks for the hint. wrote something up that works for me but wondering you have any improvements on the code? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said, I wasn't sure where to start..

After reading @BoarGules hint on having to make the date/time into something you can do arithmetic with and to use `datetime`, I've come up with the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

syslog="local4"

now = datetime.now().strftime('%b %_d %H:%M:%S')
hour = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1)
hour_ago = hour.strftime('%b %_d %H:%M:%S')

with open(syslog,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if int(line.split()[1]) < 10:
            d = line.split()[0] + '  ' + line.split()[1] + ' ' + line.split()[2]
        else:
            d = line.split()[0] + ' ' + line.split()[1] + ' ' + line.split()[2]
        if d >= hour_ago and d <= now:
            print line.strip()
```

It seems to work for what I'd like it to do but open to suggestions on improving it.
I'm just wondering if doing `if int(line.split()[1]) < 10:` is the best way to work out the spaces between the first split.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we need a function to calculate times and compare them So :

```
import datetime
def timeDiff(time1,time2):
    timeA = datetime.datetime.strptime(time1, "%H:%M:%S")
    timeB = datetime.datetime.strptime(time2, "%H:%M:%S")
    newTime = timeA - timeB
    return newTime
```

let's assume you have logfile.txt and you readed it's line  :

```
import re

with open logfile.txt as my_file :

 line_counter = sum ( 1 for line in logfile.txt)
 for i in range (line_counter):
  line  = my_file.readline() #-> Sep 8 13:25:02 blah 

  my_time = re.findall('\d+:\d+:\d+',line) #-> [13:25:02]

  if (timeDiff(re.findall('\d+:\d+:\d+',time.asctime(time.localtime()))[0] , re.findall('\d+:\d+:\d+',i)[0]) ) <=1 : # 1 hours ago 

   print line
```

Note 1 : `re.findall('\d+:\d+:\d+',time.asctime(time.localtime()))` will give you present time  and because `re`  give you a list output i used `re.findall('\d+:\d+:\d+',time.asctime(time.localtime()))[0]`

Note 2 : i used my `dateDill` func to compare them and print lines

Answer (score 0):

You need to read every line from the log file, and do some checking for each line.

```
import datetime

# get current time
now = datetime.datetime.now()

with open('yourlogfile', 'r') as f:
    # go through each line
    for ln in f:
        # ex: 'Sep 8 13:25:02 etcetcetc'
        stime = f.strip().split(' ')
        completeTime = stime[0]+ ' ' + stime[1]+ ' ' + stime[2]
        datefstr = datetime.datetime.strptime(completeTime, '%b %d %H:%M:%S')
        if (now.hour - datefstr.hour) < 1 and (now.minute - datefstr.minute) < 60:
            # do your thing here
        else: continue
```